# for_each algorithm causes basic_string::_M_construct null not valid in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, stdstring

In the project to learn C++, I have create a software compose of two easy class
(Home and People).
People have for constructor :

```
// CONSTRUCTOR
    People(): name("NoName"), first_name("NoFirstName"), age(0){}
    People(std::string n, std::string fn, int a) : name(n), first_name(fn), age(a){}
```

And Home have :

```
// CONSTRUCTOR
    Home(): adresse("NoName"){}
    Home(std::string addr): adresse(addr){}
```

In my software, a home have a vector of people, where we can add resident or remove a resident.

My error occur when I try to remove a resident in a home or when I try to print a home.

Here the code of "removeResident" :

```
void Home::removeHabitant(People const &p)
{
    this->getHabitant().erase(std::remove(this->getHabitant().begin(), this->getHabitant().end(), p));
}
```

Here the code of "operator<<" :

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, Home const &h)
{
out << h.getAddr() << "\n"; //OK 
if(h.getHabitant().size() > 0) // OK
{
    try
    {
        std::for_each(h.getHabitant().begin(), h.getHabitant().end(), [&out](People const pe){
            out << pe << "\n";

        }); // ERROR
    }
    catch(People p)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception à l'element : " << p << std::endl;
    }

}
else // OK
{
    out << "Aucun habitant !"; // OK
}
return out ;  // OK }
```

Here the output of my software :

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -c -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp -I include
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -c -o obj/People.o src/People.cpp -I include
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -c -o obj/Home.o src/Home.cpp -I include
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o bin/main obj/main.o obj/People.o obj/Home.o
./bin/main
Peoples's destructor
( NoFirstName - NoName - 0 )
10 rue des Brouettes rouge
Peoples's destructor
Peoples's destructor
( Erwan - AUBRY - 21 )
Peoples's destructor
( Roger - DURAND - 20 )
Peoples's destructor
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
makefile:6: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Aborted
```

Here the main file :

```
#include <Home.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    People erwan("AUBRY", "Erwan", 21);
    People roger("DURAND", "Roger", 20);
    People noName;

    // vector<People> lsPeople;
    // lsPeople.push_back(erwan);
    // lsPeople.push_back(roger);

    // copy(lsPeople.begin(), lsPeople.end(), ostream_iterator<People>(cout, "|"));

    Home home1("10 rue des Brouettes rouge");
    home1.addHabitant(erwan);
    home1.addHabitant(roger);

    cout << noName << endl;
    cout << home1 << endl;

    // cout << home1[0] << endl;
    // home1.removeHabitant(roger);
    // cout << home1[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After several research I think it's the cause of the home class, so here is the code of home .hpp :

```
#ifndef HOME_INCLUDED
#define HOME_INCLUDED

#include <People.hpp>
#include <vector>

class Home
{
    private:
        std::string adresse;
        std::vector<People> habitant;

    public:
    // CONSTRUCTOR
        Home(): adresse("NoName"){}
        Home(std::string addr): adresse(addr){}

    // DESTRUCTOR
        ~Home(){std::cout << "Home's destructor" << std::endl;}

    // GETTER
        std::string getAddr() const{return this->adresse;}
        std::vector<People> getHabitant() const{return this->habitant;}

    // SETTER
        void setAddr(std::string const val){this->adresse = val;}
        void addHabitant(People const &p){this->habitant.push_back(p);}
        void removeHabitant(People const &p);

    // OPERATOR
        People & operator[](unsigned int const val){return this->habitant[val];}
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, Home const &h);

#endif
```

I hope you have any idea for my problems.

PS: sorry for my english, and sorry if I have make anything of badness I'm new   as help seeker in StackOverflow

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, one small and simple program which replicates the problem that we can try ourselves. It's very likely that you will be able to find the problem yourself when creating the example.

Comment: May be, worth reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Thanks you,
But I have alrealy debug this code, and I have don't any idea why I have this error

Comment: @LecodeurEtudiant Nous n'avons pas assez d'informations, il nous manque la définition des classes et de addHabitant et des destructeurs. Avez-vous essayé une exécution sous _valgrind_ ?

Comment: I don't use valgrind no.
I have will added addHabitant and the class definition

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that `getHabitant` does not return a reference to the collection of habitants.

Comment: @LecodeurEtudiant if _valgrind_ available on your OS install it and use it, that tool is magic, easy to use (no special compilation), and incredibly useful

Comment: @bruno I have install this, the result will be put in the question.

Comment: @bruno using valgrind will neither help a beginner not point to the cause of this problem.

Comment: @rubenvb sorry but I fully disagree with that, I cannot understand how you can say that, is it also forbidden for a beginner to use a debugger ? crazy

Comment: @molbdnilo your theory has just been confirmed, might as well write that as an answer now

Comment: @bruno valgrind is not a debugger. I still highly doubt staring at memory addresses of iterators to different instances of a container will give any hints to the underlying problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As also seem by molbdnilo in a remark, in `std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, Home const &h)` you do the iteration

```
    std::for_each(h.getHabitant().begin(), h.getHabitant().end(), [&out](People const pe){
```

that supposes `h.getHabitant().begin()` and `h.getHabitant().end()` are iterators on the *same* vector but

```
std::vector<People> getHabitant() const{return this->habitant;}
```

returns each time a *new copy* of the vector.

If you do not want to modify *getHabitant* to return a const reference to *habitant* you have to memorize the vector on which you iterate.

```
std::vector<People> v = h.getHabitant();
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&out](People const pe){
```

but I encourage you to modify `getHabitant()` to be

```
const std::vector<People> & getHabitant() const {return this->habitant;}
```

Comment: Thanks you Bruno !
I have test your first solution and it work, now I have try your second solution and see if in my context which is better.

And thank you too for valgrind, this tool is very powerfull and easy to use.

Comment: @LecodeurEtudiant of course if `const std::vector<People> & getHabitant() const  ...` don't do `std::vector<People> v = h.getHabitant();` but `const std::vector<People> & v = h.getHabitant();` if you still save _getHabitant()_ result ^^

Comment: Ok ! Thanks you ^^